# HibernateSystemException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am getting **HibernateSystemException** although I did everything that is mentioned on different forums.

Here is a part of applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

I also placed @Transactional annotaion above my class.

```
@Transactional
public class MyClassImpl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) this is the wrong transaction manager:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" 
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

you need [`org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTransactionManager.html), as you can see in [13.3.3 Hibernate > Declarative transaction demarcation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-tx-declarative).

[`DataSourceTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html) is for plain JDBC, not for Hibernate (see [12.3.8 JDBC > `DataSourceTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-DataSourceTransactionManager)).

B) you need this line also:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Comment: Our another application is running with the **transactionManager** I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @imran ok, then the other app uses JDBC, not Hibernate. If the two run in parallel, you'll need two different transaction managers, see this bit for advice: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional

Comment: I was using @Transactionalbut it was not working. Actually I my class was not in the base package as defined in the applicationcontext.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that this markup is present in you application context file ?

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

It is necessary to consider your annotations.

Comment: This markup is not present in my application context file. Our another application is running successfully without this markup.

Comment: @Alex I can see no hint in the Spring docs that this is needed

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd You're right. Actually, this markup is only needed to activate **Spring** various annotations such as Autowired, PostConstruct, PreDestroy and Resource. My apologies...

Comment: @Alex to be clear: this annotation makes perfect sense and it's a great thing to have. It's just not *required* for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the tx namespace in your configuration?[image]

Comment: In my applicationContext.xml. tx is used like this <tx:annotation-driven/>

Comment: @imran tariq, if using Springsource Tool Suite, at the bottom of the editor for your xml file you should see a tab called namespaces, click on the the namespaces tab and make sure tx is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any request, you could try this piece of code :

```
Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(dataSource, null, null);
TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(dataSource, new SessionHolder(session));
```

Please keep me informed.

Comment: The whole point of using Spring's declarative transaction management is so we don't have to write infrastructure code like that