# HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am getting this exception and after a lot of R&D i am unable to resolve it.

Basically the error comes when it uses findAll() method located in `hbnpojogen-persistence-1.4.4.jar`

```
public abstract interface GenericDAO<T, PK extends Serializable>

  public abstract List<T> findAll();
```

This is the code that tried to use this method.

```
HibernateFactory.getDataDao().findAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open a transaction before executing `findAll()`. See e.g. Spring's `HibernateTransactionManager` and `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: I added all such transactions but in vain. My controller that is calling HibernateFactory.getDataDao().findAll();
is not mentioned as bean in applicationcontext.xml file. May be this is the problem. How to resolve it?

Comment: I posted code in question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571074/hibernatesystemexception-no-hibernate-session-bound-to-thread/6571532#6571532

Comment: I was using @Transactionalbut it was not working. Actually I my class was not in the base package as defined in the applicationcontext.xml file.